# Prune MySQL Table With Group By

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table like below and would like to delete all rows where the `pid`, `code` and `type` are duplicates, keeping the row with the latest `updated` date.

e.g.

```
pid     code            type    updated
267985  9414202017604   R       2017-11-13 04:52:23 -- keep
267985  19414202017601  D       2017-11-13 04:52:23 -- keep
267985  19414202017601  D       2017-11-13 04:42:26 -- delete
267985  9414202017604   R       2017-11-13 04:42:26 -- delete
267986  19414202017601  D       2017-11-13 04:32:33 -- keep
...
```

I can use `GROUP BY` to get `max(updated)` but how can I then include it in a delete statement?

Note that `updated` is not granular enough to act as a unique row identifier.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: is there an `ID` column (unique per row) in that table?

Comment: @Used_By_Already No, there is no unique `ID`. In theory the tuple `(pid, code, type)` should be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86370/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ( `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment
     ,  `pid` int
     , `code` varchar(40)
     , `type` varchar(1)
     , `updated` datetime
     , `note` varchar(9)
     , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`pid`, `code`, `type`, `updated`, `note`)
VALUES
    (267985, '9414202017604', 'R', '2017-11-13 04:52:23', '-- keep'),
    (267985, '19414202017601', 'D', '2017-11-13 04:52:23', '-- keep'),
    (267985, '19414202017601', 'D', '2017-11-13 04:42:26', '-- delete'),
    (267985, '9414202017604', 'R', '2017-11-13 04:42:26', '-- delete'),
    (267986, '19414202017601', 'D', '2017-11-13 04:32:33', '-- keep')
;

delete d
from table1 d
inner join table1 k
on k.pid = d.pid and k.code = d.code and k.type = d.type
and k.updated > d.updated
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select *
from table1 d
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/86370/1/0)**:

```
| id |    pid |           code | type |              updated |    note |
|----|--------|----------------|------|----------------------|---------|
|  1 | 267985 |  9414202017604 |    R | 2017-11-13T04:52:23Z | -- keep |
|  2 | 267985 | 19414202017601 |    D | 2017-11-13T04:52:23Z | -- keep |
|  5 | 267986 | 19414202017601 |    D | 2017-11-13T04:32:33Z | -- keep |
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This was exactly what I needed.